# What is the difference in the algorithm for noise reduction in SoX and Audacity?

Tags: audio, noise, audio-processing

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376047/what-algorithm-is-used-by-sox-swiss-army-knife-for-silence-and-noise-removal), and I understand that SoX works way FFT of the noise, then subtracting that from the FFT audio, and then resynthesizing using FFT, but I don't quite understand how this differs from [Audacity](https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/How_Audacity_Noise_Reduction_Works). I understand what FFT is, but I don't understand the rest of the explanation, and how it is different from SoX - I don't know much about signal processing. Thank you!